# native errors on DatagramChannel send

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

**Basic**

I have an app that is sending packets using DatagramChannel.send in multiple threads each to its own IP address/port and each of them keeping constant bit-rate/bandwidth. Every now and then I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

It happens on random - sometimes 5 minutes after start sometimes after a day - so I really have problems reproducing it for testing. And on my home machine I can't reproduce it at all.

**Environments**

- Windows 7, 8 and Server 2012 (all 64bit)
- 64bit Java 7 update 45

**More information**

The app is sending SI/EIT data to DVB-C network. I'm creating a list of 188-byte arrays for each of 80-120 threads and giving it to use. The thread takes the list and is looping over the list until new list is provided.

- The error usually happens on multiple channels at once. But it can happen on just one also.
- The error never happened until we had 40+ threads.
- The error happens while looping over the list, not when I'm binding new list to thread.
- The app it not running out of memory. Its usually running up to 70% of memory given to JVM.
- Strange part: If I run multiple instance of app each handling ~10 threads problems are the same.

**Simplified code sample**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  final int id = i;
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        final Random r = new Random();
        final List<byte[]> buffer = Lists.newArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
          final byte[] temp = new byte[188];
          r.nextBytes(temp);
          buffer.add(temp);
        }

        final SocketAddress target = new InetSocketAddress("230.0.0.18", 1000 + id);
        try (final DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)) {                            
          channel.configureBlocking(false);
          channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0"));              
          channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 8);
          channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
          channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_SNDBUF, 1024 * 64);

          int counter = 0;
          int index = 0;
          while(true) {
            final byte[] item = buffer.get(index);
            channel.send(ByteBuffer.wrap(item), target);
            index = (index + 1) % buffer.size();
            counter++;
            Thread.sleep(1);
          }             
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
          LOG.error("Fail at " + id, e);
        }
      }
    }).start();
}
```

---

Edits:

1) @EJP: I'm setting setting multicast properties as the actual app that I use was doing joins (and reading some data). But the problems persisted even after I removed them.

2) Should I be using some other API if I just need to send UDP packets? All the samples I could find use DatagramChannel (or its older alternative).

3) I'm still stuck with this. If anyone has an idea what can I even try, please let me know.

Comment: Why are you setting multicast properties when you aren't doing any joins?

Comment: You could try MulticastSocket. And you shouldn't be using non-blocking mode like this. Instead of sleeping, select on OP_WRITE.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and it was caused by a zero port in the target InetSocketAddress, when calling the *send* method.

In your code, the target port is defined as 1000 + i, so it doesn't seem to be the problem. Anyway, I'd log the target parameters that are used when the exception is thrown, just in case.

Comment: I didn't found the answer for this. The solution was to change the server HW, so I suspect some kind of HW malfunction or some system/network level problems.